# How to access the data from an ajax call outside the function itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

This code gets a json object from another server.

How do I access the response outside of the function?

```
(function($) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'callback',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {
            var data = json;
        }
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you show more of the structure of your program. What calls this function. What technology are you using to reply to the Ajax.

Comment: I create this to get the data for feeding a chart (amchart).

Comment: see the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yvzSL/693/

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this!

```
 _outerMethod: function(data) {
     //...do what you need to do 
 }, (function($) {
     $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: url,
         async: false,
         jsonpCallback: 'callback',
         contentType: "application/json",
         dataType: 'jsonp',
         success: function(json) {
             _outerMethod(json);
         }
     })
 })(jQuery);
```